# Remove duplicate entries from a redis queue in resque

Tags: ruby, redis, resque

I am using Resque and I have a Redis queue.It has certain duplicate entries. I need to remove the duplicate entires.How do I remove those duplicate entries? I am enqueuing the id of a certain object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into the [resque-loner](https://github.com/jayniz/resque-loner) gem. It allows you to make job queues unique. All you do is include Resque::Plugins::UniqueJob in the job classes you you to make unique.

```
class CacheSweeper
  include Resque::Plugins::UniqueJob


  class << self
    def perform(project_name)
       # some code
    end
  end
end
```